# Delete one element from each row of a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

k = [0, 1, 2]

print np.delete(a, k, 1)
```

This returns

```
[]
```

But, the result I really want is

```
[[2,3],
 [4,6],
 [7,8]]
```

I want to delete the first element (indexed as 0) from a[0], the second (indexed as 1) from a[1], and the third (indexed as 2) from a[2].

Any thoughts?

Comment: Curious if the solution posted here work for you?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach using [`boolean indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) -

```
m,n = a.shape
out = a[np.arange(n) != np.array(k)[:,None]].reshape(m,-1)
```

If you would like to persist with [`np.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), you could calculate the linear indices and then delete those after flattening the input array, like so -

```
m,n = a.shape
del_idx = np.arange(n)*m + k
out = np.delete(a.ravel(),del_idx,axis=0).reshape(m,-1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [94]: a
Out[94]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [95]: k = [0, 2, 1]

In [96]: m,n = a.shape

In [97]: a[np.arange(n) != np.array(k)[:,None]].reshape(m,-1)
Out[97]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 9]])

In [98]: del_idx = np.arange(n)*m + k

In [99]: np.delete(a.ravel(),del_idx,axis=0).reshape(m,-1)
Out[99]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 9]])
```